# Permalink with multiple custom post types (404 error)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to achieve a permalink structure with multiple custom post types inside of it. 
The first custom post type has a slug called 'service', the second custom post type has a slug called 'instructions'. The instructions post type needs to be after de service post type in the permalink.

The single page of the 'service' custom post type works, but I get a 404 page when trying to view the instructions page.

Examples:

```
    domain.com/service (works, WordPress page)
    domain.com/service/service-1 (works, custom post type)
    domain.com/service/instructions (404, WordPress page)
    domain.com/service/instructions/instruction-1 (404, custom post type)
```

Where 'service' and 'instructions' are two different custom post types, 'instructions' is the single page of the 'instruction-1' custom post type.

My Custom post types:

```
'services' => array(
    'slug' => 'service',
    'supports' => array('title','editor'),
    'internals' => array('Services','Services','All Services','Edit','Add'),
    'menu' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
    'disableadd' => false
),
```

and

```
'instructions' => array(
    'slug' => 'service/instructions',
    'supports' => array('title','editor'),
    'internals' => array('Instructions','Instructions','All instructions','Edit','Add'),
    'menu' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
    'disableadd' => false
),
```

I Hope that my question is clear enough and that someone could help me.

thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that `domain.com/service/instructions` actually matches `domain.com/service/service-1` but it tries to fetch something different, doesn't, and 404's. Does it matter what order these are defined in? Can you change the order?

Comment: This could be the issue.
The Instructions do not result in a 404 when I change the slug of the 'services' post type from 'service' to 'services'.
Is it even possible in Wordpress to achieve this url structure with the custom post types?

Comment: If you want a slug like "service/instruction" than create a taxonomy of service withing instruction post type and create terms like instruction-1 or Parent instruction etc.And later just assign terms to created instruction post type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have decided to change the 'services' slug, because changing it to a taxonomy takes to much time. I'll keep this in mind for the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't expect subfolder "a/c" slugs directly, while it can work implicitly for some time. Slugs are expected to be one-level everywhere.

Many plugins also expect it so there is a chance you will have problems with that later some day when you decide to use new plugin or update those you have.

So avoid that if you can.

Alternatively you may use unique one-level slug e.g. service_instructions at wordpress level, but create an internal rewrite of service/instructions/* -> service_instructions/* at .htaccess level.